# Submit form then clear it

Tags: reactjs, forms, reset

I am writing a budget-tracker app.  The app lists a budget amount, what has been spent so far,remaining budget, a list of expenses, and  displays a form to add new expenses. When an expense is added, it is added to the list, and all values are updated.  This works fine, except the only way I've been able to clear the add expense form after submit, is to add a reset button that resets state when clicked.  What I'm trying to achieve, is when the form is submitted, new expense is added to the list, and all values are updated, THEN the form is cleared.  Here's my AddExpenseForm.js:

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react';
import { AppContext } from '../context/AppContext';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

const AddExpenseForm = () => {
    const { dispatch } = useContext(AppContext);

    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [cost, setCost] = useState('');

    const onSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const expense = {
            id: uuidv4(),
            name: name,
            cost: parseInt(cost),
        };

        dispatch({
            type: 'ADD_EXPENSE',
            payload: expense,
        });
    };

    const reset = () => {
        setName('');
        setCost('');
    }
    return (
        <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-sm'>
                    <label for='name'>Name</label>
                    <input
                        required='required'
                        type='text'
                        className='form-control'
                        id='name'
                        value={name}
                        onChange={(event) => setName(event.target.value)}
                    ></input>
                </div>
                <div className='col-sm'>
                    <label for='cost'>Cost</label>
                    <input
                        required='required'
                        type='text'
                        className='form-control'
                        id='cost'
                        value={cost}
                        onChange={(event) => setCost(event.target.value)}
                    ></input>
                </div>
                <div className='col-sm'>
                    <button type='submit' className='btn btn-primary mt-3'>
                        Save
                    </button>
                    <button type='reset' className='btn btn-warning mt-3' onClick={reset}>Reset</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    );
};

export default AddExpenseForm;
```

I tried writing an extra function, that calls the onSubmit and then the reset function.  While there were no compile errors, when I filled out the form and saved it, the new expense was not added to the list (I expected it would be), and as a result, total spent and budget left values did not update (like they should have)

Comment: Call `reset()` after `dispatch`?

Comment: OMG! Can't believe I missed that! It worked! THANK YOU moonwave99!!!!!!!!!